# call Matlab's memmapfile with subsasgn

Tags: matlab, memory-mapped-files

I have a large writable Matlab's memmapfile object that I want to access and modify.

### Access

If I try:

```
mmap.Data.bit(1)
```

or

```
subsref(mmap.Data.bit, substruct('()', {1}))
```

I get the same value (0).

### Modify

If I try:

```
mmap.Data.bit(1) = 1
```

I can assign this value very quickly, but if I try:

```
[~] = subsasgn(mmap.Data, substruct('.', 'bit', '()', {1}))
```

Matlab stops responding and never ends the line.

What is the problem with subsasgn and mmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Matlab was actually trying to do is to load the whole content of the file.

The correct line is:

```
 [~] = subsasgn(mmap, substruct('.', 'Data', '.', 'bit', '()', {1}))
```